# Delete embedded document using mongoengine and flask

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, pull

I want to delete a embedded document with a specific '_id' using flask and Mongoengine.
Document have this structure:

```
class Main(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField(max_length=156, required = True)
    press = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField(Press))

class Press(db.EmbeddedDocument): 
_id= db.StringField()
date = db.DateTimeField(default = datetime.utcnow())
url = db.URLField()
title = db.StringField()
description = db.StringField() 
site_name = db.StringField()
url_image = db.StringField()
author = db.StringField()
```

I try using:

```
m. = Main.objects.get_or_404(slug= request.form['slug'])
m.update_one(unset__press({'_id': request.form['_id']}))
```

request.form cotaind data from a html form correctly formatted.

but does'nt work!!!
Any suggestion??
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) operator. Try:

```
m.update_one(pull__press___id=request.form['_id'])
```

Comment: SOLVED! I used that one:     m.update(pull__press___id=request.form['_id'])

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
            m.update(pull__press___id=request.form['_id'])